# Need Help regarding passing arguments and executing with multiple test cases in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

My intention is to pass multiple URL's as an argument by giving it in keyword and calling it as test case.It should be part of multiple test cases. Please help me in correcting the code.

```
*** settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Test Template     My Logging


*** Variables ***   
${Google}              https://www.google.co.in/
${Facebook}            https://www.facebook.com/



*** Test Cases *** 
Login to Google     
   My Logging     ${Google}
   My Logging     ${Facebook}

Login to Google website
    Login to Google



*** Keywords ***
My Logging
  [Arguments]     ${url}
  Open Browser     ${url}     Chrome
  Capture Page Screenshot
  Close Browser

Login to google
    Open Browser     ${Google}      Chrome
    Close Browser
```

## Error from Prompt

```
Login to Google website                                               | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid U
RL"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `Test Template` with non-data driven tests. Remove this line:

```
Test Template     My Logging
```

Comment: .Thanks for your reply.. Worked well after removing Test Template